# what's a good way to model a sequence of in a table of values?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a list of objects (called "Phases") that I'm storing in a db table.

I need to maintain the order of the Phases in the list.  I'm wondering what's a good way to model this?

I'm thinking I'll give the Phase object an "int sequence" attribute that dictates the order and since it's persisted to the table, I can read them back in order.  The only problem I see is that when I change the order of the sequence, I have to recalculate all the sequence values for every Phase in the list.  Example, swap the positions of #2 and #3 causes everything after #3 (say up to #1000) to have to be updated in the db too.

Is there an easier way to model this that I have not considered?

Comment: Why can't you use decimal ordering?

Comment: You could do it as a sort of linked list, where rather than having an ordinal you have a `next_phase_id`. Not sure if that would be easier.

Comment: Also in your example swapping #2 and #3 shouldn't mean you need to update any of the others. *Removing* #2 or #3 would mean you have to update all of them.

Comment: Are you constantly going to be reordering the Phases? If this is a less common use-case then you'll probably find incrementing 1000 values in the database takes almost no time at all.

Comment: There is no good way to represent this on RDBMS table, but application-side you can use a tree.

Comment: Not to be obtuse, but if you switch #2 and #3, wouldn't #997 still be #997?

Comment: @josh.trow Because I've never heard of "decimal ordering". :) I'll google it.

Comment: Russell & Jim Kiley -- yes, you're right!  Don't know what I was thinking. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it the way you described.

Yes if you want to insert new values, then if you've used consecutive rank values then you need to bump existing values, say

```
UPDATE table SET rank = rank + 1 WHERE rank >= ?
```

It follows that you can't usually make the rank column be unique because you don't know what order the UPDATE will be processed in.

If you're accessing the database programmatically, you could allow non-consecutive rank values, so existing ranks only need to be bumped when there isn't a gap in the numbering sequence.

Also, if you are using a row/page-based database, you could consider taking rankings out to a separate table which just has the ID of the main record, and the rank value. Then if you did need to make mass updates to rankings, you wouldn't be having to read and write entire main records, but just tiddly records containing a couple of integers.

Answer (score 0):

How to swap sort positions without impacting any other record.

```
UPDATE
  phases
SET
  sort_pos = CASE WHEN sort_pos = 2 THEN 3 ELSE 2 END
WHERE
  sort_pos IN (2, 3)
```

The only time you have a kind of 'cascade' effect is when you move one record to a new position in the sort order.

You can handle that by having the sort_pos stored as a float.  So you can push a record into sort position `2.5`.  The only down side there is that you can't then write a query that says "get me the 9th item" as it could be sort order `9` or `8.5`, or actually *any* other value what so ever.